# Why my model field is getting prepopulated in admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-users

I have created a model as below.

```
class UserPost(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='userpost', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    post_body = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default='text')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_pics', blank=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='post_likes')
```

I am not populating likes field anywhere, my admin screenshot is below.Why my likes field is getting populated with all the users created?

[admin screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBEgX.png)

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from feed.models import UserPost
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(UserPost)
```

Edit 1:
Adding a screenshot for Rishabh's answer.

[trying to add user from left as suggested by him](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pcmn8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using ManyToManyField of Django which will show you all records of User table left side and you can add them by double clicking on them or by clicking '+' sign, so your likes field is not prepopulated at all it is just showing User table data.

Comment: Hi, I have added a screenshot in edit 1 of the question, Please check, If it is like what you said, why am I unable to add from that list?

Comment: What's unclear about the error? You already have an object with that username. You don't want to create a new one, you just wait to select it to use it in that field.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought I need to select them and add them with that '+' button! Sorry, I got it now!